# Google Analytics API Migration

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

A few days ago, [Google announced this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-api-notify/browse_thread/thread/76a8ce287b4de278#):

> If you built an application on version 2.3 of the Management API, you
>   need to take action.
>
> Starting Wednesday, December 21st 2011, we plan to forward all the
>   Management API v2.3 requests to version 2.4 of the API. This change
>   will be rolled out gradually, and we expect that in a week or two, all
>   the v2.3 requests for Management API will return a v2.4 response.

They go on to say that migration is easy:

> Migrating from version 2.3 to version 2.4 is simple! All you need to
>   do is register through Google APIs
>   consolehttps://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/and add an API key
>   using the key query parameter (or an OAuth2.0 access token if you’re
>   using OAuth 2.0)

What I'm not clear on is whether or not this will actually affect my custom class, which uses the following URLs for OAuth 1.0 authentication and retrieving data from Google Analytics:

```
private $request_token_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken';
private $authorize_token_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken';
private $access_token_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken';
private $scope = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/';
```

Will my access to their API be cut off once they start forwarding requests from 2.3 to 2.4, or will this not affect me at all?

Comment: I imagine that this question would receive a better response on the [Google Analytics API discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-api?pli=1).

Comment: Advice taken.  If I get a response there I'll post it here for anyone else that may be wondering.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: For those who this helps, the answer is YES, it will be affected.